# overflow-y hidden not disabling mousewheel

Tags: css, overflow

[Link here](http://www.twelvetwelve.com/index.php)

I'm able to hide the vertical scrollbars on this page with body overflow-y hidden, but the mousewheel is still working.  The goal is to just have the viewport crop whatever it needs to of the building, with a few responsive styles to help smaller devices.  I've tried setting html and body to 100% and the background gradient stops where it should (end of viewport) but the image can still be scrolled through.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to be working correctly in Safari, what browser/version are you using?

Comment: chrome (latest autoupdate)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the scrollbars by adding `max-height: 100%` to both the `html` and `body` elements.

Comment: that seems to crop the background, so it's setting the background gradient to the proper 100% height, but you can still mousewheel down for the full image.  [see here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvukg57st5vyg82/1212.jpg)

Comment: I'm not able to recreate that in latest Chrome

Comment: are you scrolling on the page?  the scrollbar is hidden, on page load it looks perfect.  but you can still just mousewheel or swipe down below the initial 100% viewport height.